# Can I search in filenames for a String with fnmatch

Tags: python

I want to search in Folder for a file and when it detects the file he look for a string in the filename. The file is then to be moved in such a way which string was discovered.

e.g.:

I have a file named "blablie rel blub.pdf" And I am searching for either rel or musik. If its rel it should go in the Religion folder and if its musik it should go in the Musik folder.

Thats what I have:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

import fnmatch
import os
import json
import time

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    i = 1
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for file in os.listdir('.'):
            if fnmatch.filter(file, '[rel]'):
                for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                    src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
                    new_destination = folder_destination + "/Religion/" + filename
                    os.rename(src, new_destination)
            elif fnmatch.filter(file, '[musik]'):
                for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                    src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
                    new_destination = folder_destination + "/Musik/" + filename
                    os.rename(src, new_destination)


folder_to_track = "/Users/Nils/Downloads/oldfold"
folder_destination = "/Users/Nils/Downloads/newfold"
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

`[mus]` matches one character which can be `m`, `u`, or `s`. Aren't you simply looking for this?

```
if 'mus' in file:
```

Though perhaps it could be slightly more specific, like perhaps

```py
if ' mus ' in file:
```

with spaces on both sides, if your example is representative.